# How to use CSS variables with names comming from JS in VueJS?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vuetify and it creates CSS variables for every theme color (like `--v-theme-primary`)
I'd like to be able to set a color in CSS to `--v-theme-{something}` and that `{something}` to come from JS. Example:

```js
<template>
<div :class="$style['colored-text']">Asd</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const color = ref("primary")
</script>

<style lang="scss" module>
.colored-text {
    background-color: var(--v-theme-[[v-bind(color)]]);
}
</style>
```

*`[[v-bind(color)]]` is invalid syntax I came up for the demo.* **I'd like to be able to put the color name from the color ref there or something else so I can use `var(--v-theme-{color})` with color coming from js.**
In the example it'll become `var(--v-theme-primary)`

Any idea how to do it? Is it possible at all?

Comment: [classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes) are provided like `bg-primary` to apply primary color as a background, or `text-primary` to apply primary color as text color.  Instead of binding CSS styles, you can use dynamic inline classnames, e.g. `bg-${color}`

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `computed` for the css value

you can also remove `:class="$style['colored-text']"` and just use `class="colored-text"`

```html
<template>
  <div class="colored-text">Asd</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
  const color = ref("primary")
  const bgColor = computed(()=>`var(--v-theme-${color}`)
</script>

<style>
.colored-text {
  background-color: v-bind(bgColor);
}
</style>
```

[sfc example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: can we defind :root element in another file and access variable in all components, if yes could you please show how to do that as well?

Comment: I added that in the sfc for illustration purposes only. It's not in the code that's part of the answer, since vuetify should have that in there already